# Formatted printing in GDB

Tags: c, gdb

I'd like to do `printf` style printing from `GDB`. For instance, I want to print a variable value, but with some text to describe what it is. Can it be done, and if so, can you give an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a definition `int i = 5;`, you can print the value of `i` with formatted printing this way:

> (gdb) printf "Val of my object: %d\n", i
>
> Value of my object: 5
>
> (gdb)

Answer (score 16):

You can very much use `printf` in `gdb` as follows:

```
(gdb) printf "%s", x
Hello world
(gdb)
```

You can do it by using `call` also

```
(gdb) call printf("%s", x)
Hello world
(gdb)
```

I prefer the former one!

http://beej.us/guide/bggdb/ is a simple and good reference for `gdb`

Answer (score -1):

##### How to use `printf` in GDB in order to write a custom description around your variable output

> I want to print a variable value, but with some [custom] text to describe what it is.

Use `printf` with your description inside the format string:

```bash
printf "my custom description for variable 1: %s\n", my_variable_1
```

Example: use `printf "My first environment variable is: %s", environ[0]` to access the [`environ` array of environment variable strings](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html), which is automagically available in all C and C++ programs on Linux:

```bash
(gdb) printf "My first environment variable is: %s\n", environ[0]
My first environment variable is: SHELL=/bin/bash
(gdb)
```

You can print multiple variables and types, including GDB [Convenience Variables](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html) too, such as the `$i` index variable shown below. Here, I am using *two* special format characters, `%i` and `%s`:

```bash
set $i = 0
printf "environ[%i]: %s\n", $i, environ[$i++]
# now keep pressing Enter for an amazing repeat effect!
```

Example command and output after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> 3 times. Now you can see in which index in the `environ` array of strings a given environment variable string is stored! Ex: `SHELL=/bin/bash` is stored inside `environ[0]`:

```bash
(gdb) set $i = 0
(gdb) printf "environ[%i]: %s\n", $i, environ[$i++]
environ[0]: SHELL=/bin/bash
(gdb) 
environ[1]: SESSION_MANAGER=local/gabriel:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/558952,unix/gabriel:/tmp/.ICE-unix/558952
(gdb) 
environ[2]: QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
(gdb)
```

##### How to get a lot of detailed info. about your variable and its type

> but with some text to describe what it is.

For anyone landing here who just wants a really great description of a variable, use `explore value`, where `value` is your variable name.

Example output:

```
The value of 'value' is of type 'uint32_t' which is a typedef of type 'unsigned int'
'value' is a scalar value of type 'unsigned int'.
value = 1234
```

See my full answer here: [gdb: show typeinfo of some data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63404160/4561887)

##### See also

1. My much longer answer where I use the `printf` information I just learned, above: [How to print the entire `environ` variable, containing strings of all of your C or C++ program's environment variables, in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903706/4561887)