# gdb: show typeinfo of some data

Tags: c++, gdb, typeid, typeinfo

Basically, I want to get `typeid(*this).name()`, i.e. the real type of `this`.

I want to get this in GDB (without modifying the source code). I tried `print typeid(*this)` but it says that `typeid` is unknown (because I didn't included it there in the source file).

Comment: gdb doesn't support `typeid`.

Comment: same problem nowadays with lldb...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine whether an object is an instance of certain C++ class in GDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528979/how-to-determine-whether-an-object-is-an-instance-of-certain-c-class-in-gdb)

Comment: If anybody came here trying to "show type of a given variable", `whatis` command is your friend.

Comment: `ptype`, `whatis`, and `explore` (my favorite) all work, although they are all a little different. [I've written about them here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63404160/4561887)

Answer (score 82):

Use `ptype` command, like this:

```
(gdb) ptype 42
type = int
```

Comment: This returns things like `type = unsigned short`, but I want it to return `type = uint16_t` instead, so I can truly know how many bytes it is when inspecting memory. Is there any way to do that? The best I can figure out is to do `print &my_var`, which prints `(uint16_t *) 0x7ffffffefc2c`, thereby revealing that its pointer type is `uint16_t*`, meaning its type is `uint16_t`.

Comment: I presented this as an answer, but if you have a better way to do this I'm all ears: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63404160/4561887.

Answer (score 31):

### Use `ptype`, `whatis`, and `explore` (my favorite!):

Where you have a variable named `value` which is defined as:

```c
uint32_t value = 1234;
```

...the following all work:

1. `ptype value` shows `unsigned int`
2. `whatis value` shows `uint32_t`
3. `explore value` (my favorite!) shows:

   > ```
   > The value of 'value' is of type 'uint32_t' which is a typedef of type 'unsigned int'
   > 'value' is a scalar value of type 'unsigned int'.
   > value = 1234
   > ```

Example:

```bash
(gdb) ptype value
type = unsigned int
(gdb) ptype &value
type = unsigned int *
(gdb) whatis value
type = uint32_t
(gdb) explore value
The value of 'value' is of type 'uint32_t' which is a typedef of type 'unsigned int'
'value' is a scalar value of type 'unsigned int'.
value = 1234
```

Thanks to [@o11c's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568201/gdb-show-typeinfo-of-some-data/63404160#comment122923885_63404160) for pointing out the existence of the `whatis` command.

I discovered the `explore` command by running `help all` inside gdb. See my comment in the "References" section below.

#### Try it yourself:

```bash
# download the file "type_punning.c"
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Generalsimus/eRCaGuy_hello_world/master/c/type_punning.c

# build it with optimization OFF (`-O0`) and debugging symbols ON (`-ggdb`), 
# and output all intermediary files (`-save-temps=obj`), and run it in the 
# gdb debugger (`gdb bin/type_punning`)
mkdir -p bin && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O0 -ggdb -std=c11 -save-temps=obj \
type_punning.c -o bin/type_punning && gdb bin/type_punning
```

Now, with `gdb` running, do the following:

```bash
# set breakpoint to a line just after `u.value = 1234;`
b type_punning.c:52
# run to that point
r
# Now run these various commands to see what type `u.value` is:
ptype u.value
whatis u.value 
explore u.value
```

Full example commands and output:

> ```
> eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ mkdir -p bin && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O0 -ggdb -std=c11 -save-temps=obj type_punning.c -o bin/type_punning && gdb bin/type_punning
> GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1.1-0ubuntu1) 8.1.1
> Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
> and "show warranty" for details.
> This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
> Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
> For bug reporting instructions, please see:
> <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
> Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
> <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
> For help, type "help".
> Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
> Reading symbols from bin/type_punning...done.
> (gdb) b type_punning.c:52
> Breakpoint 1 at 0x70b: file type_punning.c, line 52.
> (gdb) r
> Starting program: /home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_hello_world/c/bin/type_punning 
> Type punning and ptr-based serialization demo
> TECHNIQUE 1: union-based type punning:
>
> Breakpoint 1, main () at type_punning.c:53
> 53          printf("1st byte = 0x%02X\n", (u.bytes)[0]);
> (gdb) ptype u.value
> type = unsigned int
> (gdb) whatis u.value 
> type = uint32_t
> (gdb) explore u.value  
> The value of 'u.value' is of type 'uint32_t' which is a typedef of type 'unsigned int'
> 'u.value' is a scalar value of type 'unsigned int'.
> u.value = 1234
> (gdb)
> ```

### My old/original answer

As [@Star Brilliant says here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921053/4561887), this:

```
ptype my_var
```

returns things like `type = unsigned short`, but I want it to return `type = uint16_t` instead, so I can truly know how many bytes it is when inspecting memory. The best I can figure out to get this effect is to do:

```
print &my_var
```

which prints `(uint16_t *) 0x7ffffffefc2c`, thereby revealing that its pointer type is `uint16_t*`, meaning its type is `uint16_t`.

I find this to be more-useful than `ptype my_var`, but a more direct way to get this effect is desired in case you have any suggestions.

Sample gdb commands and output:

```
(gdb) ptype my_var
type = unsigned short
(gdb) print &my_var
$27 = (uint16_t *) 0x7ffffffefc2c
```

Again, notice `ptype my_var` reveals it is an `unsigned short`, whereas `print &my_var` reveals the more-detailed and desired answer which is that it is a `uint16_t`.

### References:

1. [@o11c's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568201/gdb-show-typeinfo-of-some-data/63404160#comment122923885_63404160)
2. [@Star Brilliant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921053/4561887)
3. `help all` - I used this command while running `gdb`, copy-pasted the output all to a text editor, and searched for "type" to discover the `explore` command.

### See also:

1. My answer on [How to view a pointer like an array in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64055978/4561887)
2. My answer on [How to use `printf` in GDB in order to write a custom description around your variable output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903487/4561887)
3. [my ans.] ["gdb" debugger skips a break point weirdly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995063/gdb-debugger-skips-a-break-point-weirdly/69547096#69547096)
4. [my Q&A] [What's the difference between a compiler's `-O0` option and `-Og` option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386189/whats-the-difference-between-a-compilers-o0-option-and-og-option/63386263#63386263)
5. [my Q&A] https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349047/where-do-i-find-core-dump-files-and-how-do-i-view-and-analyze-the-backtrace-st

<sub>Keywords: how to run gdb; how to view variable types and values in gdb; how to build and compile for gdb debugging symbols</sub>

Comment: `whatis` is a thing.

Comment: @o11c, thanks! It turns out `explore` is a really nice command too. I've just massively updated my answer.

Comment: while in TUI mode (split screen with source code; `tui enable`), when I executed `explore somevariable`, the *gdb* prompt showed "*... Continue exploring it as a pointer to a single value [y/n]:*". But I couldn't enter any answer (*y* or *n*). It seems the TUI mode swallowed my answer input. I first had to cancel the `explore somevariable` command by pressing `Ctrl+c Ctrl+d`, then disable TUI mode with `tui disable`. Repeating `explore somevariable` now allowed me to answer the question.

Comment: @Abdull, I think you just need to press `Ctrl` + `X`, then `o`, to switch focus back from the TUI window to the 'o'ther window where the GDB commands go. I have that command saved [in my notes here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/git%20%26%20Linux%20cmds%2C%20help%2C%20tips%20%26%20tricks%20-%20Gabriel.txt#L1703). Search the doc for `Ctrl + X, o`.

Comment: `Undefined command: "explore"` for me in GDB 8.3.1

Answer (score 18):

The `ptype [ARG]` command will print the type.

Comment: At least in gdb v7.6.1 that doesn't help with this question, as it only prints the static type, not the polymorphic type. For example where "d" is an object of type "D" derived from base class "B" then
`B* b = &d;

(gdb) ptype b
type = class B {`

Comment: [with "set print object on" it gets prefixed with `type = /* real type = D * */` but then so does "whatis"]

Answer (score 14):

This question may be related: [vtable in polymorphic class of C++ using gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529561/vtable-in-polymorphic-class-of-c-using-gdb):

```
(gdb) help set print object
Set printing of object's derived type based on vtable info.
```

It's not exactly typeid() but it should show the real object type when inspecting a polymorphic pointer (e.g. `this` in a base class). Naturally works only for classes with a vtable (i.e. at least one virtual method) but so does `typeid`.