# How to view a pointer like an array in GDB?

Tags: c, gdb

Suppose defined: `int a[100]`  Type `print a` then gdb will automatically display it as an array:`1, 2, 3, 4...`. However, if `a` is passed to a function as a parameter, then gdb will treat it as a normal int pointer, type `print a` will display:`(int *)0x7fffffffdaa0`. What should I do if I want to view `a` as an array?

Comment: Cast it to an array type, or use the `x` command.

Comment: Related for assembly code without types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300718/printing-array-from-bss-in-gdb

Answer (score 182, accepted):

See [here.](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Arrays.html) In short you should do:

```
p *array@len
```

Comment: I have to know the number of len, is it possible to just use something like `command array`?

Comment: @CodyChan When a is passed as parameter to a function you can't do that as gdb will not know the size.

Comment: @CodyChan You can pass a number somewhat larger, and it _probably_ won't crash. Just so you can get an idea of what's going on.

Comment: The link is bad now.

Comment: @GabrielStaples thank you for reporting this. It now points to similar resource

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, glad to help! I've also added an answer, demonstrating some nice formatting options, and showing various samples of gdb output, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64055978/4561887.

Answer (score 28):

`*(T (*)[N])p` where T is the type, N is the number of elements and p is the pointer.

Comment: It first casts `p` to a pointer-to-array type (instead of pointer-to-element type pointing to the first element), then dereferences that pointer to get an array object. In C, this would decay back to a pointer in most contexts except as the operand of `&` or `sizeof`, but gdb uses the array type directly to print the array.

Comment: Simpler: `(T[N])*p`. GDB is a bit more able than C ;)

Comment: print/x *(char(*)[20])str

Answer (score 19):

Use the `x` command.

```
(gdb) x/100w a
```

Comment: This yields too much output. Ivaylo's seems better.

Comment: It's an overly specific solution. Whilst it will work for the OP's usecase with `int`s, it won't help e.g. if array contains `struct`s.

Answer (score 17):

#### How to view or print *any number of bytes* from *any array* in *any `printf`-style format* using the `gdb` debugger

As [@Ivaylo Strandjev says here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14502287/4561887), the general syntax is:

```bash
print *my_array@len
# OR the shorter version:
p *my_array@len
```

Example to print the first 10 bytes from `my_array`:

```bash
print *my_array@10
```

**[Recommended!] Custom `printf`-style print formatting:** however, if the commands above look like garbage since it tries to interpret the values as chars, you can force different formatting options like this:

1. `print/x *my_array@10` = hex
2. `print/d *my_array@10` = signed integer
3. `print/u *my_array@10` = unsigned integer
4. `print/<format> *my_array@10` = print according to the general [`printf()`-style format string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), `<format>`

Here are some real examples from my debugger to print 16 bytes from a `uint8_t` array named `byteArray`. Notice how ugly the first one is, with just `p *byteArray@16`:

```bash
(gdb) p *byteArray@16
$4 = "\000\001\002\003\004\005\006\a\370\371\372\373\374\375\376\377"

(gdb) print/x *byteArray@16
$5 = {0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0xf8, 0xf9, 0xfa, 0xfb, 0xfc, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xff}

(gdb) print/d *byteArray@16
$6 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1}

(gdb) print/u *byteArray@16
$7 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255}
```

In my case, the best version, with the correct representation I want to see, is the last one where I print the array as unsigned integers using `print/u`, since it is a `uint8_t` unsigned integer array after-all:

```bash
(gdb) print/u *byteArray@16
$7 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255}
```

### Going further

[Comment question from @Abdull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502236/how-to-view-a-pointer-like-an-array-in-gdb/64055978?noredirect=1#comment135563125_64055978):

> Is there a way to print the array without specifying the array length, for pointer-based arrays which mark the end of the array with a null pointer such as [`extern char **environ`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)?

Yes, there are many ways. See my long answer here: [How to print the entire `environ` variable, containing strings of all of your C or C++ program's environment variables, in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903706/4561887).

### References

1. [How to view a pointer like an array in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14502287/4561887)
2. Official GDB documentation: Ch. 10.4 Artificial Arrays: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Arrays.html
3. Official GDB online user manual: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/
4. Official GDB online user manual (all on one page, for easy searching!): https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb

### See also

1. My answer on [gdb: show typeinfo of some data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63404160/4561887)
2. My answer on [How to print the entire `environ` variable, containing strings of all of your C or C++ program's environment variables, in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903706/4561887)

Comment: is there a way to print the array without specifying the array length, for pointer-based arrays which mark the end of the array with a null pointer such as [`extern char **environ`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)?

Comment: @Abdull, yes, there are many ways I just figured out. See my small master's thesis in my new answer here: [How to print the entire `environ` variable, containing strings of all of your C or C++ program's environment variables, in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903706/4561887).

Answer (score 1):

`(int[100])*pointer` worked for me thanks to suggestion in the comments by @Ruslan