# Gdb - print array or array element, with element of various size

Tags: assembly, gdb

Assembly code (`yasm`):

```
section .data
src db 1,2,3
```

Each element of `src` array is 1 byte.

In `GDB`, how to print the whole array or an element at specified index, e.g print the element with value 2.

Comment: `p/x (char[3])src` ? to print the entire array of 3 elements.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Cool ! And it seems `p/x ((char[4])src)[1]` could print individual element of array. If you put it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Feel free to produce an answer. Glad it was helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing "array" from .bss in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300718/printing-array-from-bss-in-gdb)

Answer (score 5):

(*Ok, I'd like to put an answer by myself, with @Michael Petch's permission, to make it more clear for future searcher*)

The code & answer are for **x86-64** linux system, variables are defined in assembly the `.data` section.

---

### Code

**tmp.asm** (*yasm*)

```
; yasm assembly program,
; compile: yasm -f elf64 -g dwarf2 tmp.asm && ld tmp.o
; execute: ./a.out

section .data
a db 1
b dw 2
c dd 4
d dq 0x1234567890abcde

arr_a db 1,2,3,4
arr_b dw 1,2,3,4
arr_c dd 1,2,3,4
arr_d dq 1,2,3,0x1234567890abcde

section .text
global _start

_start:
    mov rax,1

    ; exit
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,5
    int 0x80
```

---

### Print array or array element in GDB

In GDB:

- `p` command will treat a variable as **4 byte**;
- `x` command will treat a variable as **8 byte**.

So, need different ways to print a number of size 1 / 2 / 4 / 8 bytes.

**Examples commands:**

- `p` for 4 bytes.

  - `p/x c`, print `c` as 4 byte, this is default.
- `p` with cast, for 1 / 2 byte

  - `p/x (char)a`, print `a` as 1 byte
  - `p/x (short)b`, print `b` as 2 byte
- `x` for 8 bytes

  - `x/x &d`, print `d` as 8 byte, this is default.
- `x` for 1 / 2 / 4 bytes

  - `x/bx &a`, print `a` as 1 byte,
  - `x/hx &b`, print `b` as 2 byte,
  - `x/wx &c`, print `c` as 4 byte,
- `p` for array

  - `p/x arr_c@4`, print `arr_c` as array of length 4, contain elements of 4 byte, this is default.
  - `p/x (char[4])arr_a`, print `arr_a` as array of length 4, contain elements of 1 byte,
  - `p/x (short[4])arr_b`, print `arr_b` as array of length 4, contain elements of 2 byte,
  - `p/x (long[4])arr_d`, print `arr_d` as array of length 4, contain elements of 8 byte,
- `p` for individual array element

  - `p/x ((long[4])arr_d)[1]`, treat `arr_d` as array of length 4, contain elements of 8 byte, and print the element with index 1.

**Tips:**

- It seems `p` could print 8 byte array, but can't print individual 8 byte value correctly (which is not part of array). In that case, use `x` instead.

*(This is just tested on my machine, if there is any issue, please feel free to correct it.)*

Comment: `x/s &string` if `string` is a byte array.