# Is there any reason that a heap pointer would not get assigned to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, gdb

The structure of Node is the following:

```cpp
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
    bool someBool;
};
```

I have the following couple of lines:

```cpp
    Node *hello = new Node{data, cur, !new_head}; // line A
    array[new_head_index] = hello;                // line B
}                                                 // line C
```

Value of `new_head_index` is confirmed to be 1 by GDB on all 3 lines.

GDB confirms, on lines A, B, and C, when I do `p *hello` (print the contents of `hello`), I get:

```
(gdb) p *hello
$7 = {data = 888, next = 0x8414e70, someBool = false}
```

But printing the contents of `array@2` (array has length 2, declared in main as `Node *heads[numHeads] = {new Node{0, nullptr, false}, nullptr};`) has this on lines B and C (before line is actually executed):

```
(gdb) p **array@2
$8 = {{data = 777, next = 0x8414e70, someBool = true}, {data = 33, next = 0x378, someBool = 112}}
```

(The 777 node is expected, I filled it in before).

While on line A, it has:

```
(gdb) p **array@2
$9 = {{data = 777, next = 0x8414e70, someBool = true}, {data = 61265, next = 0x0, someBool = false}}
```

Essentially, `hello` is not being assigned to `array[1]`. What could be a possible reason for this?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:
main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "new_mod.h"
using namespace std;

int len(Node **array) {
    int i = 0, count = 0;
    while (array[i++]) { ++count; }
    return count;
}

void attach(Node **array, int head, int index, int data) {
    Node *hello = new Node{data, cur};
    array[new_head_index] = hello;
}

int main() {
    string command;
    int head;
    Node *array[numHeads] = {new Node{0, nullptr}, nullptr};

    while (cin >> command) {
        if (command == "a") {
            int m, x;
            cin >> head >> m >> x;

            attach(array, head, m, x);
        }
    }

}
```

mod.h

```
#ifndef MOD_H
#define MOD_H
#include <ostream>

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
    bool someBool = false;
};

const int numHeads = 2;

void attach(Node **array, int head, int index, int data);
#endif
```

Try putting in this input (I've named this file `a.in`)

```
a 0 0 777
a 0 1 888
```

Compile with `g++ -Wall -g main.cc -o newe` so you can do things with gdb!

By the way, here's what I did in gdb to get the above problem:

```
gdb newe
b attach(Node**, int, int, int)
run <a.in
layout n
c
n
n
n
n
n
n
n          (comment: I did n until line Node *hello = new Node{data, cur};)
p **array@2
n
n
p **array@2 (the problem is shown)
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be a whole lot easier to look at.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok here you have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Node *array[2]` and `Node **array` are *not* the same thing, and when you ask GDB to `p **array@2`, you are asking to interpret array as if `array` was a double pointer, not an array.

You can observe this before starting the input loop:

```
(gdb) p *array@2
$1 = {0x55555556ae70, 0x0}
(gdb) p *array[0]
$2 = {data = 0, next = 0x0, someBool = false}
```

Here, you can see that `array` is in expected state: first node is all zeros, second is NULL.

But when you do:

```
(gdb) p **array@2
$3 = {{data = 0, next = 0x0, someBool = false}, {data = 4113, next = 0x3737203020302061, someBool = 55}}
```

you can immediately see that you are not looking at the right data: you *know* that `array[1]` is NULL, so it *can't* be pointing to a `Node` with `4113` in it.

I don't believe there is a GDB built-in syntax to `print *array[0 .. N]`.
One possible solution is to define a helper function (which can easily be generalized to take the array name and size as parameters, but is kept trivial here for simplicity):

```
(gdb) def parray
Type commands for definition of "parray".
End with a line saying just "end".
>print *array[0]
>print *array[1]
>end
(gdb) parray
$4 = {data = 0, next = 0x0, someBool = false}
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, attach (array=0x7fffffffdb70, head=0, index=1, data=888) at foo.cc:34
34          array[new_head_index] = hello;
(gdb) n
35      }
(gdb) parray
$5 = {data = 777, next = 0x55555556ae70, someBool = false}
$6 = {data = 888, next = 0x55555556ae70, someBool = false}
```

Comment: I don't even know what a double pointer is.. But when I started to use gdb a week ago, I looked up how to do "print an array", I found this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502236/how-to-view-a-pointer-like-an-array-in-gdb. And I thought this was working well up until now for the arrays I've tried in the past. Is this answer wrong then?

Comment: The answer is not wrong, and `print *array@2` is working correctly. But you don't want to print the pointer values of array elements; you want to print *dereferenced* pointers, and that is different.

Comment: Also, the other question is "how to print pointer as an array". Here you *have* an array, so simple `p array` works to print its values.

Comment: What is the difference? I can't find anything when I search for "pointer values of array elements". Do you just mean addresses? I mean `array` in this case is an array of pointers, that's why you have to dereference it twice, otherwise it will give you addresses (I think by "pointer value" you might mean address), but if it was just a pointer of something like an `int` or a `struct`, then something like `p *array@2` did not give me addresses, it gave me the actual values.. How do you explain this?

Comment: " "Also, the other question is 'how to print pointer as an array". Here you have an array, so simple `p array` works to print its values." `p array` only prints `$13 = (Node **) 0x7ffffffee150` in my example. Is this what you are referring to as the "array"? This isn't useful information for me.