# How to print out full argv values in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

I am debugging with  arguments in gdb:

```
gdb --args ./buildData data/test.data features/testFeatures.txt test
```

Then in gdb I set a break point in the 'main' function and want to print out the argv's value:

```
print *argv
```

But this  only  displays the first argument, not all:

```
print *argv
$2 = 0x7fffffffe4f0 "/src/tools/./buildData"
```

Shouldn't it print out all 3 arguments?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14502287/4655217 p argv@argc

Comment: No, argv is a pointer. try `print argv[1]`, `print argv[2]`, etc?

Comment: @geobreze but in other cases, print *someObject can always print out the pointer's value. Why can't it do for *argv? Is that because *argv is a pointer to an array?

Comment: @marlon array is just a pointer to the first element. When you're accessing *array it's the same as *(array + 0) which is equal to array[0]. Same with other indexes: *(array + 1) equal to array[1] and so on.

Comment: Anyway linked answear is perfect solution, just do `p *argv@argc` [gdb doc](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Arrays.html).