Printing C arrays passed into functions in lldb
Is it ever possible to use lldb's various variable formatting options for arrays that have been passed to a function? I have a simple C array that I pass into a quicksort function like this:
int main(void)
{
   int array[] = {3, 0, 9, 4, 2, 17, 99, 69, 7, 1};
   int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

   quicksort(array, 0, size-1);

   return 0;
}

Using the parray command prints each element on a newline. I would like lldb to format it more or less like this when I set it as a display item:
   int a[] = {3, 0, 9, 4, 2, 17, 99, 69, 7, 1};

(Note my quicksort function uses "a" as the name of the array parameter.)
However, none of the options I've tried from the lldb documentation or seen suggested on here for similar questions are able to achieve this. Here are some things I've tried:
var *a -c

var a --count 10 --format d

type summary add -x "int \[[0-9]+]" -c

To reiterate, I only have the issue when I've stepped inside the function. I believe that my issue stems from the fact that in C, arrays decay to pointers when passed to functions, but I'm not knowledgeable enough about C or lldb to troubleshoot further. Isn't there a way to tell lldb to treat int pointers as arrays of ints when inside a given function? Thanks in advance for considering.
EDIT: Since a poster below asked, here is the declaration of the quicksort function:
void quicksort(int a[], int low, int high);


Hmm, how does quicksort() know that array is an array of int?  I'd expect something to  indicate the type for this C code.  Is this quicksort() only for an array of int?

Here's the way to do it in gdb: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14502236/5382650 lldb should be similar

When you pass array to quicksort() it decays to a pointer. Pointers don't carry any size information, so the debugger doesn't know the length and can't print it as an array.

I don't think the question here is about how to get lldb to print this array contents, since parray is how you do that.  The question is how to get this not to print as an array - one element per line - but in a single line, more like the way the initializer would look.  You can't use a type summary or synthetic child provider.  Those are for printing single values, but to print this array correctly you need two values, the buffer and the length.

If you want to have this print on a single line you would need to write your own version of the parray command that prints the output however you would like.  More information about doing that is here: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html#create-a-new-lldb-command-using-a-python-function.  Also, feel free to ask for an option to condense this printing.  lldb does that for small structures by default, but not for arrays.  You would do that here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues.

try " p (int()[arrayElementCount])a " , where arrayElementCount is to be replaced by the number of elements in the array a

@chux it's indicated in the function definition, which I did not post here for brevity.
@JimIngham Thanks Jim for your thorough consideration of my question. I will make the request and check out the custom command link.
@ticktalk This returns this error:
(lldb) p (int()[5])a error: <user expression 1>:1:7: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector     1 | (int()[5])a       |  ~~~~~^~

@friendlyman23 "Isn't there a way to tell lldb to treat int pointers as arrays of ints when inside a given function?" --> well that should be in the function declaration that you have omitted from post.  Please reconsider and post your  declaration of quicksort().  I suspect it is not "indicated in the function definition" as you suggest.

@friendlyman23 Another idea.  Perhaps your implementation uses array is a special way.  Try the same task yet with something more abstract like abc.

@chux Sorry, I mixed up declaration and definition. I posted the declaration above.

A function that takes a pointer and an int and treats the pointer as a buffer of the int size is a very common pattern in C.  However, just because you pass a pointer and int doesn't mean they will be treated that way.  In the example there are two ints, how would lldb know a priori which is the size?  There's no way to indicate that usage in C.  But you can convey this to lldb by using the parray command: parray a <count> that tells lldb to print the result of the expression: a treating it as an array of count elements.  That's working here.  This problem is just the output format.

BTW, the almost correct cast expression is (lldb) p (int[5]) a but that will give you an error because lldb's expression evaluator is a "language accurate" parser, and the cast from "type *" to "type[N]" is not allowed in C.
