# Get class name which has an attribute in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

In `gdb` is it possible to know the name of the class that has a certain attribute?

Here is an example:

```
class A
{
    public:
    int my_val;
};

class B: public A
{
    public:
    int my_other_val;
};

class C: public B
{
    public:
    int my_other_other_val;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    C obj1;
    obj1.my_val = 10;
}
```

From `obj1` can I know the name of the `class` with has the attribute `my_val`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gdb: show typeinfo of some data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568201/gdb-show-typeinfo-of-some-data)

Comment: @kiner_shah No, it doesn't. None of the answers mentions getting the class of which the variable is member of.

Comment: What does "From `obj1`" mean? `p obj1` comes back with `$1 = {<B> = {<A> = {my_val = 0}, my_other_val = -7112},`, so once you get used to gdb's terse output, this shows that `my_val` is defined in `A`.

Comment: Before printing `p obj1` it is worth to enable pretty printing with `set print pretty`. The output will be much more readable.

Comment: This is an example with a small amount of attributes. If each class has 15-20 variables inside (exaggerated example)  is there  a way to check which class has a certain attribute from the `print`?

Comment: This could be done with [python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Types-In-Python.html). Recursively go through all `Type.fields()` until you find the one with the matching `name`.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in one of the comments, you can add a command that meets your needs using GDB's Python API.  The details of which can be found [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html).

To get you started, here's a rough first cut.  Place the following into a file called `find-attr.py`:

```
import shlex

class FindAttrCommand(gdb.Command):
    """find-attr VALUE NAME

    Search through all the fields in VALUE, and any base classes of
    VALUE, looking for a field NAME.  Print out some information for
    any matching fields found.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        gdb.Command.__init__(self, "find-attr", gdb.COMMAND_DATA)

    def check(self, path, type, name):
        if path == "":
            path = type.name
        else:
            path = path + "::" + type.name
        for field in type.fields():
            if field.name == name:
                print(f"Found {path}::{name}")
            if field.is_base_class and field.type is not None:
                self.check(path, field.type, name)

    def invoke(self, arg_str, from_tty):
        args = shlex.split(arg_str)
        value = gdb.parse_and_eval(args[0])
        type = value.type
        self.check("", type, args[1])

FindAttrCommand ()
```

Then in a GDB session:

```
$ gdb -q ./findit
Reading symbols from ./findit...
(gdb) source find-attr.py
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x401111: file findit.cc, line 24.
Starting program: /tmp/findit 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffaea8) at findit.cc:24
24      obj1.my_val = 10;
(gdb) n
25      return 0;
(gdb) find-attr obj1 my_val
Found C::B::A::my_val
(gdb) q
```

There's still lots of things that could be added to the Python script, for example:

- it has no error handling at all,
- you might want to add an option that allowed for regexp matching of the field name,
- you could add command completion.

There's probably more that could be done, but hopefully you can expand this as needed.